# Upgrading to Bluez 5.19 from source

Tags: package-management, bluetooth, make, source, wii

I've successfully compiled Bluez 5.19 from source using ./config and then make, but I'm stuck on the next step.  Make install doesn't seem to overwrite the old Bluez (when checked with dpkg -l, it still reports bluez 4.1 even after a restart).

So, I thought uninstalling bluez and then doing make install would work, but I discovered I can't apt-get remove or apt-get purge bluez without uninstalling a bunch of other extremely important packages (such as ubuntu-desktop).  Re-installing these packages shoves the old 4.1 bluez back in whether I want it to or not.

What should I do in order to use Bluez 5.19 on my system?

(My goal is to pair my Wii U Pro controller and a newer generation Wii Remote with my computer, and according to what I've read, the new version of bluez will accomplish this for me).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Accourding to what you have read where? The ubuntu wiki has very straightforward instructions: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CWiiD

Comment: This page's instructions do not work for newer generation Wii Remotes or Wii U Pro Controllers.  Again, bluez is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

If you already ran "make install" and there were no error, you are probably OK.

"make install" will not do anything to the package information, so you system will still have the old package installed

What it does is install the new software in /usr/local/bin (if you kept the default configuration)

The old software should still be in /usr/bin . By default Ubuntu first check /usr/local/bin

You can check by doing

```
which hciconfig
```

in a terminal. it will tell you if you are using the new version (/usr/local/sbin/hciconfig) or the old one (/usr/sbin/hciconfig)

If you feel adventurous, you can remove the executable associated with the old bluez packages